# How to call external input and output file names to run Python Programs at Linux Command Prompt

Tags: python, linux, file-io, command-prompt

In my Python Program, I have lines to open an input file:

```
f = open('/home/han/fasta.txt',"r")
```

and to write an output file:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write ("{:<16}{:<16}{:<16}{:<16}{:<16}".format('','A','C','G','T')+'\n')
```

However, every time I want to run the Python program in Linux Command Prompt with different, I have to change the input and output file names in codes.
I would like to know how to achieve running the program at Linux command prompt exactly as below: (in which I need to enter "-i" and "-o" for input and output file names respectively)

```
$ python codon.py -i fasta.txt -o output.txt
```

I have tried for the input file name

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
f = open(filename,"r")
```

but I felt it doesn't necessarily need the "-i" in command prompt.

Sorry if the question is incredibly obvious...I am new to Python

Comment: You don't have to require the `-i`, but it's good practice to do so.  You probably want to look into the `argparse` module, which will help specify what parameters you want and parse them out of `argv` for you, and can also generate a nice usage statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use python standard `argparse` library

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My app description')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Path to input file')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Path to output file')
args = parser.parse_args()

f = open(args.input,"r")
```

....etc

Comment: if the path of the input and output file is always the same. But the names of the input and output files change how could I do that in the python program and have only the command: python3 program.py -i inputfile.xml -o outputfile.csv ? Please.

Thanks for your help and your time !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `-i`, which isn't strictly obligatory, you can do as follows:

```
python codon.py fasta.txt output.txt
```

And you can get the names by using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`:

```
from sys import argv
inputfile = argv[1]
outputfile = argv[2]
f = open(inputfile ,"r")
...
```